# Is there a word for the pattern on pancakes and grilled cheese?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’d like to know if there’s a word to describe the somewhat similar pattern that appears when you brown pancakes and buttered slices of bread on a pan. Does “freckled” work?

[image: pancake]

[image: grilled cheese]

Comment: I don't think there is any regularity to that crisping pattern.

Comment: When I read the question title, my first thought was that it was  going to be about a religious figure appearing — phew!

Comment: When something is cooked and that darkens its color, you can just use the word you mentioned—"**browned**." If your emphasis is on the actual distribution of the pattern of darkening, you'll have to resort to another word, but you should also make it clear from the context. Simply saying "I grilled the sandwich until it was nicely mottled" is, as comments have noted, so rare a usage that its cognitive dissonance is off-putting.

Comment: Probably not what you want, but there is *patina*.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use **mottled**, certainly for the first picture.

> *mottled*:
>
> Something that is mottled has spots or patches with different shades
> or colors, like the reddish blotches that can appear on your skin if
> it’s exposed to extreme temperatures.

[[Vocabulary.com: Dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mottled)]

Many moths, and a type of sculpin, are described as 'mottled'; in these cases, underlying patterns can be discerned.

Skin can indeed become mottled, and pictures on the internet can look unappetising, but a mottled apple can be more attractive. There is rarely patterning in such cases.

[image]

['Chenango Strawberry'; [AdamApples](https://adamapples.blogspot.com/2017/10/chenango-strawberry.html)]

The filigree patterning of your first picture could also be described as **lacy**, while a display of more chunky sectors could be described as **crazed**.

Comment: Exactly the word. However, I totally disagree with the sentiment in the last sentence (is it a quote?) - a mottled apple does not look attractive to me.

Comment: Be that as it may, saying a grilled cheese sandwich is mottled makes me gag.

Comment: Even if it's chateau-mottled?

Comment: [*This recipe makes fully, **mottled pancakes** with crips edges. If you want solid-colored pancakes, use little to no fat on the griddle.*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Maple_Syrup/8XnRDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mottled+pancakes&pg=PT54&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

[Speckled](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/speckled) is also a good word for something which is covered in small dots or patches. The Macmillan online dictionary defines it as

> covered with a lot of small spots or marks

With the example

> a speckled hen

A [freckle](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/freckle) on the other hand is defined by the same dictionary is defined as

> a small brown spot on your skin

so "freckled" is not applicable to any other surface than skin, and usually human skin at that. It could be used metaphorically but not literally.

You could also use [dappled](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dappled)

> covered with or forming areas of lighter and darker areas of colour or shadow

But that is usually used to refer to the ground under trees in sunlight or to horses with spotty coats. "Speckled" or "mottled" as suggested by Edwin Ashworth are probably the best choices.